# How to poptoRootViewController from presented ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have login screen after login I m pushing to HomeViewController. On HomeViewController I have a button "Setting" on pressing which I am presenting "SettingViewController", Now on settingViewController I have button for Logout.
  Now when user press logout it should popToRootViewController.ie on LoginScreen but it is not being done. any suggestions.
Here is my code.

on login

```
-(void)login_Success
{
HomeViewController *homeView = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:homeView animated:YES];
}
```

on home presenting setting screen

```
- (IBAction)btn_setting_Click:(id)sender
{
SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc]init];
[self presentModalViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES];  
}
```

on setting screen loggout pressed

```
- (IBAction)btnLogout_Click:(id)sender
 {
[appDelegate closeSession];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 [[[self parentViewController]navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

This is not popping to Login screen on pressing logout. Any suggestions.

Comment: login screen is rootViewController, now pushed screen is Home screen. then i Presented settingScreen..on pressing logout button from setting screen it is not poping to root view controller. i used the above code to popToRootViewController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First define method in AppDelegate like following:

```
-(void)logoutNav
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

then try following code at SettingViewController

```
- (IBAction)btnLogout_Click:(id)sender
 {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) logoutNav];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have presented your view controller in between. So in next view popping will not be available. Not even for rootViewController.

You need to dismiss your view, then pop to your previous view

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: if i dismiss the modal then it will show the home screen and then popToRootViewController. which may not look good. any other suggestions please

Comment: if you will dismiss then it won't show the home screen, it will show your "settingsViewController". & yes it will not look good, but since you have presented view controller, you have to do dismiss only..

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)btnLogout_Click:(id)sender
{
   [appDelegate closeSession];
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
   [[self.view.window.homeView navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I am not sure but try this

**EDIT**

Using delegate try to implement this like this

SettingViewController.h

```
@protocol SettingsViewControllerDelegate
    -(void)logOut;
@end
...
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<SettingsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

SettingViewController.m

```
@synthesize @delegate;

- (IBAction)btnLogout_Click:(id)sender
{
    [appDelegate closeSession];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.delegate logOut];
}
```

HomeViewController.h

```
#import "SettingViewController.h"
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <SettingsViewControllerDelegate>
```

HomeViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)btn_setting_Click:(id)sender
{
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc]init];
    settingsViewController.delegate = self
    [self presentModalViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES];  
}

-(void)logout
{
    [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have edited post with delegate for you. but you got something working. thats nice